# Hidden Stacklayout taking up space in xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm creating a form in Xaml using Xamrin which  contains absolute layout in which i'm hiding a stacklayout. but one more stacklayout just down below of hidden stacklayout but hidden stacklayout is taking up space.

What i want to do.When i did hide one stacklayout another stacklayout should take place of hidden staklayout.

Comment: Please, share your code. The behavior you want is that one that should be default on xamarin forms. There's something wrong with the environment or code... (Sorry for the poor english)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Thanks for help and supports.**

**I've resolved the issue:**

I followed this link
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/83632/hiding-and-showing-stacklayout in this link they said that use grid and make row height auto and it will automatically adjust the extra space of layout.

```
<Grid VerticalOptions="Fill">    
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Spacing="20">
        <StackLayout Margin="10,0">  
            <Label Text="lable 1" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="Small" />
            <Label Text="lable 2" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="Small" />
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding IsStudent}" Margin="10,0">  
            <Label Text="lable3" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="Small" />
            <Label Text="lable 4" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="Small" />
            <Label Text="lable 5" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="Small" />
            <Label Text="lable 6" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="Small" />
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" Spacing="20" >
        <local:Button
            x:Name="btnSave"
            Text="Submit"
            VerticalOptions="End"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy, Converter={x:Static local:InverseBoolConverter.Instance}}"
            AutomationId="saveButton" /> 
    </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 5):

No need for a grid.
Set the IsVisible AND HeightRequest properties.

```
 MyStackLayout.IsVisible = false;
 MyStackLayout.HeightRequest = 0; // trigger recalc of space layout.
```

The change in heightrequest triggers the desired recalculations.

Answer (score 1):

I've too looked into why those hidden controls are taking space and well... they ARE taking space and that's it.
You can do a simple addition and removing of labels. Something like this:

```
public class MyStack : StackLayout
{
    Label
        _label1 = new Label(),
        _label2 = new Label(),
        _label3 = new Label();

    public void ShowLabels()
    {
        Children.Add(_label1);
        Children.Add(_label2);
        Children.Add(_label3);
    }

    public void HideLabels()
    {
        Children.Remove(_label1);
        Children.Remove(_label2);
        Children.Remove(_label3);
    }
}
```

Comment: If that is still true, then it is a bug. Doc says: [VisualElement.IsVisible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.visualelement.isvisible?view=xamarin-forms) - "Setting IsVisible to false will remove the element from the visual tree. The element will no longer take up space in layouts".  However, if trying to get a *dynamic* re-layout when changing isVisible in code, may have to do something else to force a layout - as in phil soady's answer. Still seems suspiciously like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

My recomendation is putting a StackLayout at the bottom of the content, in order to keep the original height of the other elements at the top.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="CentroDono.Views.YOURVIEWPAGE"
              Title="YOURVIEWTITLE"
             x:Name="YOURPAGECONTENTNAME">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
        <!--VISIBLE CONTENT-->
            <Label Text="HELLO"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="FOOTER"/>
            <!--INVISIBLE CONTENT-->    
            <Label x:Name="_searchText"  Text="Result1" IsVisible="False"/>
            <Label x:Name="_searchText2"  Text="Result2" IsVisible="False"/>
            <Label x:Name="_searchText3"  Text="Result3" IsVisible="False"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Needs explanation. How do the invisible labels at the bottom affect the layout?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, it seems it doesn't works as display: none for css... it always uses the space, no matter if is visible or not...

Comment: Hmm. Maybe that is (or was) a bug. [VisualElement.IsVisible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.visualelement.isvisible?view=xamarin-forms) - "Setting IsVisible to false will remove the element from the visual tree. The element will no longer take up space in layouts".

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, that's even better... Thanks for the tip!